# create just a return method to a EXE file from BLUEJ

Tags: java, return, exe, bluej

i have just this code:

```
import java.util.Calendar;
public class Contigencia
{  
    public String Contigencia(){
        int ano = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int mes = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int dia = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        mes = mes + 1;

        String Contigencia;
        int anoC, mesC, diaC;
        diaC = 200 - dia;
        mesC = mes*3;
        anoC = 9999 - ano;

        Contigencia = ("" + diaC + mesC + "0" + anoC);

        return Contigencia;
    }
}
```

And I want to create a executable file, for when I execute the file, show me the `String Contigencia`, like in this return.

Answer (score 0):

BlueJ allows you to create **executable** JARs.

In other words: you can package a Java application into a single JAR, which you can later "launch" using some wrapper script. See [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=npnSIuImXa0) for a video tutorial on how to do that.

Creating a *real binary executable* is something completely different; and not something that BlueJ is capable of doing.

You can look into [launch4j](http://hbogos.blogspot.co.uk/2016/05/tutorial-how-to-convert-jar-to-exe.html) for the later.